# nodemailer authentication issues

Tags: node.js, authentication, office365, nodemailer

this is the first time i am using nodemailer, and i am having issues authenticating my details with godaddy.

This is the function i have in my node.js/express backend router:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const simplesmtp = require("simplesmtp");
const MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
const imaps = require("imap-simple");

// Function to send an email
function sendEmail(data) {
  // SMTP configuration
  const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.office365.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: true,
    tls: {
      ciphers: "SSLv3",
      minVersion: "TLSv1.2", // Use TLS 1.2 or higher
    },
    auth: {
      user: "myemail@mydomain.com",
      pass: "mypassword",
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    to: data.email,
    from: "myemail@mydomain.com",
    subject: "Test Email",
    text: data.message,
  };

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Error sending email: ${error}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Email sent: ${info.response}`);
    }
    smtpTransport.close();
  });
}

// Function to create the SMTP server for receiving emails
function createSMTPServer() {
  // Create a simple SMTP server to receive emails
  const server = simplesmtp.createServer({
    debug: false,
  });

  server.on("startData", (connection) => {
    console.log(`Message from: ${connection.from}`);
    console.log(`Message to: ${connection.to}`);
    connection.saveStream = new MailParser();

    connection.saveStream.on("end", (mail) => {
      console.log("Received email:");
      console.log(`Subject: ${mail.subject}`);
      console.log(`From: ${mail.from.text}`);
      console.log(`To: ${mail.to.text}`);
      console.log(`Body: ${mail.text}`);
    });

    connection.pipe(connection.saveStream);
  });

  server.listen(25);
}

// Function to connect to the IMAP server and start listening for emails
function connectToIMAPServer() {
  // IMAP configuration
  const imapConfig = {
    imap: {
      user: "myemail@mydomain.com", // Replace with your Office365 email address
      password: "mypassword", // Replace with your Office365 email password
      host: "outlook.office365.com",
      port: 993,
      tls: true, // Use TLS encryption
      authTimeout: 10000, // Set an authentication timeout
    },
    onmail: (numNewMsgs) => {
      console.log(`You have ${numNewMsgs} new email(s).`);
    },
  };

  // Connect to the IMAP server and start listening for emails
  imaps
    .connect(imapConfig)
    .then((connection) => {
      return connection.openBox("INBOX").then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to IMAP server");
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`Error connecting to IMAP server: ${err}`);
    });
}

// Handle the /contact route
router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  if (
    data.name.length === 0 ||
    data.email.length === 0 ||
    data.message.length === 0
  ) {
    return res.json({ msg: "Please fill out all the fields" });
  }

  // Send an email
  sendEmail(data);

  // You can also start the SMTP server for receiving emails if needed
  // createSMTPServer();

  // Connect to the IMAP server and start listening for emails
  connectToIMAPServer();

  res.json({ msg: "Email sent and listening for incoming emails" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

of course i have my real email and password in there.

and this is the error message i am receiving in the VSCode console:
`[0] Error sending email: Error: 34400000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:` 
I have tried other versions of this code, and i have only received other error messages such as failed to authenticate. I am using the normal password I use to login to my godaddy/office365 email address.

I spoke to goDaddy, and they gave me the config settings i need -
Username: Email address
Password: Email password Incoming settings
Server name:
outlook.office365.com (POP/IMAP)Port:
POP: 995 with SSL selected
IMAP: 993 with SSL selectedEncryption method:
TLS (POP/IMAP) Outgoing settings
Server name:
smtp.office365.comPort:
587Encryption method:
STARTTLS

when i told them that i am still having issues, they said that it is on my end, not their end.

is there anyone who can help me with this?

UPDATE:
when i used a much simpler version of the function:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body;
  if (
    data.name.length === 0 ||
    data.email.length === 0 ||
    data.message.length === 0
  ) {
    return res.json({ msg: "Please fill out all the fields" });
  }

  let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Godaddy",
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "myemail@mydomain.com", // Your GoDaddy email address
      pass: "mypassword", // Your GoDaddy email password
    },
  });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to: "myemail@mydomain.com", // Your GoDaddy email address
    subject: `Message from ${data.name}`,
    html: `
    <h3>Informations</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Name: ${data.name}</li>
    <li>Email: ${data.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${data.message}</p>
    `,
  };

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => {
    try {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Failed to send email" });
      }
      console.log("success");
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "Message was sent successfully" });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err)
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ msg: "There was an unexpected server error." });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

it gave me the following errors:

```
[0] Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed for myemail@mydomain.com
[0]     at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)        
[0]     at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1564:34)[0]     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:546:26)
[0]     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)    
[0]     at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
[0]     at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)       
[0]     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[0]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
[0]     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
[0]     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
[0]   code: 'EAUTH',
[0]   response: '535 Authentication Failed for myemail@mydomain.com',
[0]   responseCode: 535,
[0]   command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
[0] }
```

then it started giving me this error:

```
[0] Error: Mail command failed: 550 User myemail@mydomain.com has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 5 recipients out of 5 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 13.69 hours.
[0]     at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)        
[0]     at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1594:34)        
[0]     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1063:18)        
[0]     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)    
[0]     at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
[0]     at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\Baily\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)       
[0]     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[0]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
[0]     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
[0]     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
[0]   code: 'EENVELOPE',
[0]   response: '550 User myemail@mydomain.com has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 5 recipients out of 5 allowed have been sent. Relay 
quota will reset in 13.69 hours.',
[0]   responseCode: 550,
[0]   command: 'MAIL FROM'
[0] }
```

even though i have not succeeded in sending / receiving a single email like this.
it is also weird that there is a limit of only 5 emails in every 24 hours....

Comment: I can notice it's complaining from using 'ssl' do you actually need it? try commenting it or use lower version. Or even commenting all 'tls' data. I believe if you don't use tls no need to be secured.

Comment: when i tried doing this, i got this error

Error sending email: Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [AM0PR06CA0074.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com 2023-09-10T18:41:09.408Z 08DBAF90A9662C63]

Answer (score 1):

when i face this problem i was using google account (Gmail serves ) and i solve it by enable 2step verification

also you can read that
https://www.courier.com/error-solutions/535-authentication-failed-nodemailer/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any 2FA authentication ? Maybe u need to configure ur mail for 3rd party software login permission.

Comment: when i spoke to godaddy they told me I should use my normal password...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should consider using an app password for third-party services with your Google account, follow these steps:

1. **Enable Two-Factor Authentication:**

   - Go to your Google Account settings.
   - Navigate to the security section and enable Two-Factor Authentication.
2. **Create an App Password:**

   - In the Google Account settings, locate the search bar and type "App Password."
   - Select "App Password" from the search results.
   - Create an app password for your email account. This password will be a hexadecimal code.
3. **Using the App Password with Nodemailer:**

   - You can now use this app password with Nodemailer to authenticate your email.
4. **Separate Email for Authentication and Sending:**

   - It's a good practice to use a different email address for authentication (e.g., for logging into your Google Account) and for sending emails. This enhances security and separates concerns(sometimes we are not able to send mail, if we use same email for both).

By following these steps, you'll be able to generate and use an app password for third-party services like Nodemailer

Comment: At least try out the solution before voting negative, i got the same problem when using nodemailer and i resolved it using the app password from my  google account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).